# obj icon on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Just wondering if you have ever run across this.  On Internet Explorer I get a little OBJ icon next to a PNG icon.  I have 5 pngs and 6 of these stupid little OBJ icons.  Any idea where they are from or how to get rid of them?  You can see it here: http://www.yoomerang.com/faq (assuming your in IE)

This does not show up on any other browser, so it is really hard to troubleshoot.  Also, could be something completely unrelated to the images, but that is what they are closest to. I have plenty of other pngs in the site, no issues...just these specific ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p>￼<img src="" alt="" class="">
```

Firefox tells me that the line of code up here is the source code for your problem.

Remove the character between `<p>` and `<img>` and the OBJ will dissapear.

Comment: I threw the code into Text Wrangler and then 'zapped all the gremlins' worked great.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

This often appears when you copy the texts from PDF.
As Kevin mentioned, if you find this,you need to sanitize the texts well.

Comment: I was caught out with this - possibly because of copying text from a PDF. Interestingly, the text was pasted into a (CMS's) TinyMCE editor which didn't indicate the presence of the unicode characters (that @Pumbaa80 mentioned - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm). Should have 'Zapped Gremlins' from the raw HTML in TextWrangler early on as Kevin-Z suggested rather than trying to find it via TinyMCE HTML editor.

Answer (score 2):

They show up in my copy of Firefox too.

They are just characters (non-printing ones I think) in your source code, that appear between the start tag of the paragraph and the start tag of the image.

Comment: It's the [Object replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm) (whatever that is...)

Comment: I threw the code into Text Wrangler and then 'zapped all the gremlins' worked great.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked in the IE, select developer tools (F12). 
The paragraph ( `<p>` ) has a Text attribute and it is set to OBJ (Text = "OBJ").